# Stamps that can almost instantly deliver letters or packages to any destination

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a long shot because my recollection is rather vague, but around 40 years ago when I was a kid, I read a story about a boy who somehow acquired special stamps. If you addressed a letter to a dead person and put one of these stamps on it, the stamp would deliver the letter and bring a reply back. I believe he uses them to communicate with his dead mother. He might even be able to watch the letters float away to their destination. That is about all I remember about it. I'm not even completely sure it was stamps and I'm not totally sure it was a boy, there is a possibility it was a girl.

Comment: Reminds me of Robert Arthur's ["Postpaid to Paradise"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68402) aka "Postmarked to Paradise" aka "The Stamps of El Dorado". Man inherits funny stamps (of the "Federated States of El Dorado") from his father; watches letters float out the window; comes back stamped "RETURN TO SENDER. NO SUCH PERSON AT THIS ADDRESS". However, the guy in Arthur's story does not communicate with any dead relatives. Hero and friend decide to mail themselves to El Dorado but hero chickens out.

Comment: You are sure that the main character is a boy or a girl, not a grown man? And you are sure that he corresponds with dead people? So we can rule out the story I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: The story you are describing sounds very familiar. I'm starting to believe that I'm remembering two different stories as one. The story you mentioned and another one with a kid contacting their dead mother in some way. I'm going to get a hold of the story you mentioned so I can read it and see if it helps my memory.

Comment: In that case, I think I'll post "Postpaid to Paradise" as an answer. If it turns out you are remembering two different stories, you can post a new question for the other one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You indicated in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80363/stamps-that-can-deliver-letters-to-dead-people-and-bring-an-answer-back#comment170781_80363) that you might be conflating two different stories. **Parts** of your description match the short story ["Postpaid to Paradise"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68402) (aka "Postmarked for Paradise" aka "The Stamps of El Dorado") by [Robert Arthur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Arthur_Jr.), the first in his series of [*Murchison Morks*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?23117) stories. First published in [*Argosy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argosy_(magazine)), June 15, 1940, it was reprinted in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, Winter-Spring, 1950](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61458), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v001n02_1950-Winter-Spring_AK/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v001n02_1950-Winter-Spring_AK#page/n61/mode/2up). If you read it around 40 years ago, it could have been in [this Damon Knight anthology](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?40846) or in [this Asimov-Greenberg anthology](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?40986). Here are some details from the story to help you remember if this is one that you read before.

There is no communication with dead people in "Postpaid to Paradise". It was not a boy or girl but a grown man . . .

> It was Hobby Week at the Club, and Malcolm was displaying his stamp collection.
>
> "Now take these triangulars," he said. "Their value is not definitely known, since they've never been sold as a unit. But they make up the rarest and most interesting complete set known to philatelists. They—"
>
> "I once had a set of stamps that was even rarer and more interesting," Murchison Morks interrupted. Morks is a small, wispy man who usually sits by the fireplace and smokes his pipe, silently contemplating the coals. I do not believe he particularly cares for Malcolm, who is our only millionaire and likes what he owns to be better than what anybody else owns.

. . . who inherited the stamps from his father:

> I am not a stamp collector myself [he began, with a pleasant nod toward Malcolm] but my father was. He died some years ago, and among other things he left me his collection.

Here is a description of the stamps (which were quite a bit larger than regular stamps):

> It is true the subjects they depicted were far from usual. The ten-cent value, for instance, depicted a unicorn standing erect, head up, spiral horn pointing skyward, mane flowing, the very breathing image of life.
>
> It was almost impossible to look at it without *knowing* that the artist had worked with a real unicorn for a model. Except, of course, that there aren't any unicorns any more.
>
> The fifty-center showed Neptune, trident held aloft, riding a pair of harnessed dolphins through a foaming surf. It was just as real as the first.
>
> The one-dollar value depicted Pan playing on his pipes, with a Greek temple in the background, and three fauns dancing on the grass. Looking at it, I could almost hear the music he was making.

Morks is especially fascinated by the three-dollar stamp:

> A native girl, against a background of tropical flowers, a girl of about sixteen, I should say, just blossomed into womanhood, smiling a little secret smile that managed to combine the utter innocence of girlhood with all the inherited wisdom of a woman.
>
> Or am I making myself clear? Not very? Well, no matter. Let it go at that. I'll only add that on her head, native fashion, she was carrying a great flat platter piled high with fruit of every kind you can imagine; and that platter, together with some flowers at her feet, was her only attire.

The five-dollar stamp, not so much:

> This one was relatively uninteresting, by comparison—just a map. It showed several small islands set down in an expanse of water labeled, in neat letters, *Sea of El Dorado*. I assumed that the islands represented the Federated States of El Dorado itself, and that the little dot on the largest, marked by the word Nirvana, was the capital of the country.

Just for fun, Morks puts an El Dorado stamp on a letter to his friend Harry in Boston. While he's looking for a regular stamp to put with it, the letter disappears. Just as he's about to give up looking for it, he gets a phone call:

> It was Harry Norris, calling me from Boston. His voice, as he said hello, was a little strained. I quickly found out why.
>
> Three minutes before, as he was getting ready for bed, the letter I had just finished giving up for lost had come swooping in his window, hung for a moment in midair as he stared at it, and then fluttered to the floor.
>
> The next afternoon, Harry Norris arrived in New York. I had promised him over the phone, after explaining about the El Dorado stamp on the letter, not to touch the others except to put them safely away.

They try an experiment:

> "I'll tell you!" Harry exclaimed at last. "We'll send something to El Dorado itself!"
>
> I agreed to that readily enough, but how it came about that we decided to send, not a letter, but Thomas à Becket, my aged and ailing Siamese cat, I can't remember.

They put the cat in a box with air holes, address it to a made-up address (*Mr. Henry Smith, 711 Elysian Fields Avenue, Nirvana, Federated States of El Dorado*), stick a 50-cent stamp on it, and watch what happens:

> For a moment, nothing whatever happened.
>
> And then, just as disappointment was gathering on Harry Norris' countenance, the box holding Thomas à Becket rose slowly into the air, turned like a compass needle, and began to drift with increasing speed toward the open window.
>
> By the time it reached the window, it was moving with racehorse velocity. It shot through and into the open. We rushed to the window and saw it moving upward in a westerly direction, above the Manhattan skyline.
>
> And then, as we stared, it began to be vague in outline, misty; and an instant later had vanished entirely.

The cat comes back:

> Outside the window was the package we had just seen vanish. It hung there for a moment, then moved slowly into the room, gave a little swoop, and settled lightly onto the table from which, not two minutes before, it had left.
>
> Harry and I rushed over to it, and our eyes must have bugged out a bit.
>
> Because the package was all properly canceled and postmarked, just as the letter had been. With the addition that across the corner, in large purple letters, somebody had stamped, RETURN TO SENDER. NO SUCH PERSON AT THIS ADDRESS.
>
> "Well!" Harry said at last. It wasn't exactly adequate, but it was all either of us could think of. Then, inside the box, Thomas à Becket let out a squall.
>
> I cut the cords and lifted the lid. Thomas à Becket leaped out with an animation he had not shown in years.
>
> There was no denying it. Instead of killing him, his trip to El Dorado, brief as it was, had done him good. He looked five years younger.

The success with the cat emboldens them to mail themselves to El Dorado, addressed to the Postmaster General. Harry goes first. Morks changes his mind after he looks in an atlas and finds that there is no such place on earth as the Federated States of El Dorado. Instead he uses the last stamp to send Harry's bag after him:

> I got up and fetched Harry's bag. It was summer, luckily, and he had brought mostly light clothing. To it I added anything of mine I thought he might be able to use, including a carton of cigarettes, and pen and ink on the chance he might want to write to me.
>
> As an afterthought I added a small Bible—just in case.
>
> Then I strapped the bag shut and affixed the tag to it. I wrote *Harry Norris* above the address, pasted that last El Dorado stamp to it, and waited.
>
> In a moment the bag rose in the air, floated to the window, out, and began to speed away.

Comment: I thought of that story too, although I discounted it due to the whole "communicate with the dead" aspect.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm conflating this story with another. So, I'm going to accept this answer. There is no point in creating a question about the other story because all I remember about it is that a boy communicates with his dead mother in some way. Thank you for the answer user14111.

Comment: ...now I want to know how it ends! :D Did the package reach Harry Norris? Did he reply?

Comment: @AndresF. SPOILER WARNING! SPOILERPHOBES BEWARE! DON'T READ THIS COMMENT! No word from Harry.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe perhaps ["The Love Letter"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?95066) by Jack Finney, first published in 1959? It has some similarity.

[Plot summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Love_Letter_%281998_film%29):

> In 1959, Jake Belknap, a young, lonely, single man in Brooklyn, New
> York is looking for used furniture to furnish his recently acquired
> apartment. Walking in a section of the borough that contains very
> large, ancient, magnificent mansions about to be torn down, he finds a
> yard sale of antique furniture from a mansion about to be demolished,
> and is fascinated by an antique roll-top desk from the 1800s, which he
> purchases.
>
> After getting the desk home, he opens a drawer and finds original
> stationery from the previous century, along with several old stamps
> from that period. He also finds a love letter from a woman named Helen
> Elizabeth Worley, who lived in the Brooklyn of the 1880s, to a man
> whom she dreams about, although she is about to be engaged to man she
> doesn't love.
>
> Enchanted with the letter, he feels compelled to answer Helen, by
> writing to her using the old stationery, pen and ink, and putting an
> 1869 stamp on the letter (from his collection) and mailing it at the
> old "Wister" post office, which has been around since the 19th century
> in Brooklyn, unchanged by time.
>
> He returns home and opens the second drawer, to find to his shock,
> that Helen has received his letter, and she wishes to know who he is
> and why he has written to her. He writes her another letter,
> describing who he is, and the fact that he lived in the year 1959 and
> although they have fallen in love with each other, to meet is
> impossible because of the years between them. Expecting to receive a
> final, long love letter from her, he is surprised to find in the
> bottom drawer, only her picture and the inscription "I will never
> forget".
>
> After doing research on her whereabouts, he finally finds her grave in
> a local cemetery, and on her tombstone is engraved, "I never forgot".
> Miss Worley had died in 1934.

[Full text here](http://richters-time.blogspot.com/2007/09/love-letter-by-jack-finney.html).

Comment: It has some similarities, but I don't think that is the story. I'm pretty sure it was a child and that they were communicating with their dead mother or possibly grandparent.